# In how many ways five distinct balls can be put into the boxes if each box can hold at most one ball and no two boxes without balls are adjacent?

Tags: combinatorics

Eight boxes are arranged in a row. In how many ways can five distinct balls can be put into the boxes if each box can hold at most one ball and no two boxes without balls are adjacent?

**Attempt:** Choose the pair of boxes without balls first. There are $7$ ways to do this.

Then choose the other box without balls. There are $6$ ways to do this.

Then subtract the number of ways which the $3$ boxes are together. There are $6$ ways to do this.

Thus there are $36$ ways to choose empty boxes, and $5!$ ways to choose how to put in the balls, so we get $4320$.

I'm right?

Comment: I am coming up with something different. I agree with N.F. Taussig's answer.

Comment: @MathLover The problem says that no two empty boxes are adjacent.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig yes you are right. I read it wrong. To OP, $4320$ should be deducted from total arrangements ${8 \choose 5} \cdot 5!$ and that gives $2400$

Comment: I think you must edit your question to indicate that the boxes are indistinguishable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Line up five unmarked boxes in a row.  Arrange the five balls in those boxes, which can be done in $5!$ ways.  Doing so creates six spaces in which to place an empty box.
$$\square b_1 \square b_2 \square b_3 \square b_4 \square b_5 \square$$
To ensure that no two of the three empty boxes are adjacent, choose three of these six spaces in which to place an empty box, which can be done in $\binom{6}{3}$ ways.  Now, number the boxes from left to right.  Hence, there are
$$5!\binom{6}{3} = 2400$$
admissible arrangements.